# Process.Start is not working after hosting asp.net web application in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis

I have a return a c# code to save a file in the server folder and to retrieve the saved file from the location. But this code is working fine in local machine. But after hosting the application in IIS, I can save the file in the desired location. But I can't retrieve the file from that location using

```
Process.Start
```

What would be the problem? I have searched in google and i came to know it may be due to access rights. But I don't know what would be exact problem and how to solve this? Any one please help me about how to solve this problem?

To Save the file:

```
string hfBrowsePath = fuplGridDocs.PostedFile.FileName;
if (hfBrowsePath != string.Empty)
{
    string destfile = string.Empty;
    string FilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SharedPath") + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("PODocPath") + PONumber + "\\\\";
    if (!Directory.Exists(FilePath.Substring(0, FilePath.LastIndexOf("\\") - 1)))
       Directory.CreateDirectory(FilePath.Substring(0, FilePath.LastIndexOf("\\") - 1));
    FileInfo FP = new FileInfo(hfBrowsePath);

    if (hfFileNameAutoGen.Value != string.Empty)
    {
        string[] folderfiles = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath);
        foreach (string fi in folderfiles)
        File.Delete(fi);
        //File.Delete(FilePath + hfFileNameAutoGen.Value);
    }
    hfFileNameAutoGen.Value = PONumber + FP.Extension;
    destfile = FilePath + hfFileNameAutoGen.Value;
    //File.Copy(hfBrowsePath, destfile, true);
    fuplGridDocs.PostedFile.SaveAs(destfile);
}
```

To retrieve the file:

```
String filename = lnkFileName.Text;
string FilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SharedPath") + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("PODocPath") + PONumber + "\\";
FileInfo fileToDownload = new FileInfo(FilePath + "\\" + filename);
if (fileToDownload.Exists)
     Process.Start(fileToDownload.FullName);
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What happens instead?

Comment: How are you saving a file in the server folder and retrieving the saved file from the location, provide code. And what are you doing in `Process.Start`

Comment: log error info, paste here; perhaps you're having partial trust issues on shared hosting.

Comment: Hi, I have added the code to save and retrieve the file. Please check my question again.

Comment: Suggestion: Use `Path.Combine` to create a file or folder path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like folder security issue. The folder in which you are storing the files, *Users* group must have *Modify* access. Basically there is user(not sure but it is IIS_WPG) under which IIS Process run, that user belongs to *Users* group, this user must have *Modify* access on the folder where you are doing read writes.

**Suggestions**

- Use `Path.Combine` to create folder or file path.
- You can use `String.Format` to create strings.
- Create local variables if you have same expression repeating itself like `FilePath.Substring(0, FilePath.LastIndexOf("\\") - 1)`

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I can create the file. But the only problem is I cant view the saved file. where i can find the IIS_WPG user and how to give modify permission?

Comment: If you can save file, then it's not security issue. Can you check if you are saving and retrieving same file? You can also try throwing error `if (fileToDownload.Exists)` fails. And what is `PONumber`, you are saving file with that name and retrieving using `lnkFileName.Text`

Comment: actually PONumber is an autogenerated one. The selected file will save in the folder as PONumber + its extension. For ex: Notepad file would be saved in the folder as 'PO-11-009.txt'. So after saving the file, the file name 'PO-11-009.txt' would be assigned as the text to the LinkButton. So I can retrieve the filename by getting the LinkButton Text.

Comment: In that case your `Process.Start` will try to launch `.txt` file, and it will try to open default editor for this, most probably it will be notepad. But don't think IIS has access to launch Notepad, need to check. What are you trying to achieve with `Process.Start`?

Comment: Process.Start(filenamewithfullpath); In that I give the full path of the file to open. By using this, I just want to open the file in the path.

Comment: Open? Can you explain? Do you want to download that file? or open locally in notepad (default editor)?

Comment: Not to download. Just to view what file is saved.

Comment: Where do you want to view? If it's on production server, then you will need to Remote Desktop to that machine. Secondly as i said IIS can not launch Notepad.exe unless and untill it has access to do that... If you want to view the content of file on .aspx page, just read the file and use `Respose.Write` to write it on web page.

Comment: How to give access to the IIS?

Comment: You can go through [this](http://forums.iis.net/p/1174735/1967915.aspx). I will suggest, you give the download link to the file and when user clicks it, it will open it in notepad directly.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to give permissions to the application pool that you are running. see this link http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

You can also use one of the built-in account's "LocalSystem" as application pool identity but it has some security issue's.